# Is it correct to say "Be careful! Your foot may get scraped on the wall" or "Be careful! Your foot may get squashed on the wall"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

[image]

A boy is rocking a plastic horse which is too close to a wall.

Is it correct to say "**Be careful! Your foot may get scraped on the wall**" or "**Be careful! Your foot may get squashed on the wall**"?

Comment: You can say neither to a very young child. In any case, scrape and squash are not usually used in the passive voice. But no wall will crush his foot.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Obviously ***scrape*** and ***squash*** mean different things, but *in principle* you might warn the child about the possibility of either or both of those actions happening to his foot. Which do you ***want*** to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about protecting the child, and not about English grammar, try

> If you rock your horse close to the wall you might hurt your foot.

... perhaps accompanied by a visit to the wall and a gentle demonstration of what might happen.

Then keep a close eye.

If the picture is accurate, "stay on the rug" might be even better.